# Where do I get my drivers

Tags: drivers, sony

I have a sony laptop and I can't find my drivers that are going to be compatible with Ubuntu no matter where I look, does anybody have somewhere to recommend for me? Thanks guys.

Comment: I need the drivers specifically for my PCI and for my USB

Comment: The PCI bus does not use drivers.  Your USB controller should also just work, why do you think you need drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Graphics drivers: either:

- Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software sources > Additional drivers > [the middle one]

or

- http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

But you'll probably also want to check out http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide for more detailed help info before you got started.

Other drivers? I run a Sony Vaio and I've never needed anything except Catalyst. What are you missing?